# How to count two column with the third column in another table?

Tags: laravel

The idea is I have a table `events`:

[image]

The column `Mark_id` has a relationship with another table called  `mark_events` :

[image]

The relation in model Event :

```php
public function markevent() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\MarkEvent', 'mark_id', 'id');
}
```

What I need is `count` these columns ( `status` , `diabetes` , `number_mark_event` ) and save the total of these number  in  `sum` column

Code of Controller:

```php
$form = [
    'mark_id' => $request->mark_id,
    'status' => $z,
    'diabetes' => $request->diabetes,
];

$event = Event::update($form);
```

Comment: 2 links for you: 1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins  2. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202758/bad-practice-to-store-calculated-data-in-database

Comment: @user3532758 can you explain ?

Comment: 1. You need to join the two table to access fields or columns from both tables at the same time. You need to read up about joins. 2. You are trying to store calculable data in database, which is not a good practice, but this maybe subjective, hence, the second link to read about that too.

Comment: @user3532758 Yeah I get all of the columns but how can I count the number inside these columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and count the columns. This works as you only retrieve the counted columns, joins can provide side effect if returning ambiguous columns.

```
$eventCounts = Event::leftJoin('mark_events', 'events.mark_id', '=', 'mark_events.id')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(status) as status_count'), DB::raw('count(diabetes) as diabetes_count'), DB::raw('cout(number_mark_event) as  number_mark_event_count'))
    ->get();

$eventCounts->status_count;
$eventCounts->diabetes _count;
$eventCounts->number_mark_event_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I write this solution for the example you posted

In update method in Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $event = Event::where('mark_id',$request->mark_id)->firstOrFail();
    $sum = $event->status + $event->diabetes + $event->markevent->number_mark_event;

    $event->update([
         'sum' => $sum
    ]);
```